# Messages loss in Thingsboard

Tags: thingsboard, thingsboard-gateway

I am trying to send messages to google pubsub through Thingsboard using MQTT broker . I am using only one instance of Thingsboard and thingsboard is installed on kubernates. But there I am facing messages loss. Is single instance cause this problem or any thing else is there ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look in the Thingsboard logfile, if there are any errors regarding data processing.

Also you could consult the API Usage Dashboard (Rule Engine --> View Statistics) if there are errors in rulechains.

You may also consider increasing the performance by changing the internal queue of Thingsboard to Kafka or Confluent Cloud (if not already used)

Comment: If we are using only one instance of things board and sending messages in Bulk using many devices i.e (1000 devices ). So can Single  instance take these all load or it may be a cause for message loss ? @mdeuchert

Comment: In microservice deployment it makes sense to use at least 2 nodes in order to distribute the data load. But also a Single Instance could probably handle this. There may be a bottleneck somewhere. So please consult the Log oder API Usage Dashboard to identify where it is slowing down.

Comment: I tried to debug Things board as you mentioned But again at things board side I am not getting those messages in api use.                                                                                           My use case is - I am sending data from Apache JMeter for load testing using MQTT broker.